# Indicate an object's method through his pointer in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, opengl, glfw

I'm currently learning OpenGL in C++.

I'm trying to read the keyboard inputs by setting `glfwSetKeyCallback(this->window, ctrl->key_callback);` Where `this->window`is my `GLFWwindow* window` and `ctrl->key_callback` is a method of my custom object `Controller`.

I'm getting a compiler error with MSVC:

> non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

How can I indicate the `key_callback` method trough that `Controller* ctrl` pointer?

Where the error pops out:

```
void Class1::set_callback(Controller* ctrl)
{
    glfwSetKeyCallback(this->window, ctrl->key_callback);
}
```

Controller.h

```
#include "Class1.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

class Controller
{
    public:
        Controller(Class1* c);
        ~Controller();
        void key_callback(GLFWwindow* glwindow, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);

    private:
        Window* window;
};
```

I'm calling set_callback in main.cpp

```
#include "Class1.h"
#include "Controller.h"

int main()
{
    Class1* my_class = new Class1();
    Controller* controller = new Controller(my_class);
    my_class->set_callback(controller);
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if I didn't formulate my question/title right, I'm pretty confused with this syntax

Comment: @max-langhof Yep thank you, I just didn't know how to formulate this question on the search engine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Non static member function have a this parameter. The signature of `void key_callback(GLFWwindow* glwindow, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)` is actually `void key_callback(Controller*this, GLFWwindow* glwindow, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)`. So it simply not meet the requirement of `glfwSetKeyCallback`.

I suggest you to use a thunk function (a standalone function or a static member function):

```
void key_callback_thunk(GLFWwindow* glwindow, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    auto self = static_cast<Controller*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(glwindow));
    self->key_callback(glwindow, key, scancode, action, mods);
}

void Class1::set_callback(Controller* ctrl)
{
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(this->window, ctrl);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(this->window, key_callback_thunk);
}
```

Note that `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` can only store one pointer for a given window. You call it again, the value will be overrided.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll need to find another way by calling glfwSetKeyCallback in the `Controller` Class

Comment: @GriffinBabe I modified the answer to give a way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a member function for a callback, [`glfwSetKeyCallback`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga7e496507126f35ea72f01b2e6ef6d155) takes a pointer to a free function. It's signature is

```
GLFWkeyfun glfwSetKeyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, GLFWkeyfun cbfun);
```

where `GLFWkeyfun` is

```
typedef void(* GLFWkeyfun) (GLFWwindow *, int, int, int, int);
```